# Single Line string is failing during deserialization using Jsonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following line of code

```
public T PostData<T>(string url, object content) 
{
 var result = default(T);
 var response = string.Empty;

 // other lines of code setting up client in between .. ignoring them  for readability

 response = client.UploadString(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), contentString);
 result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response, settings);
}
```

result line is where the code is failing.
The above post content is called from

```
public string GetCustomer(CustomerReq request)
 {
   var url = string.Format(_apiUrl + "/GetCustomer");
   var result = _webApiRouter.Route<string>(url, Enums.HttpMethodType.Post, request);        
   return result;
   }
```

The above code is where we pass the type as string.
It works fine for all objects until I get a  as string and respone is one word ex: "test"

Int , byte , double seem to work fine .
So now I want it as below. What is the best way to handle this code in a if condition

```
if (response = string i.e one word )
    result =(T)Convert.ChangeType(response, typeof(T));
```

Comment: _"result line is where the code is failing"_ - how is it failing? Exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: `What is the best way to handle this code in a if condition` - why do you think an `if` _is_ the best way to handle this?

Comment: _"The above post content is called from"_ - I don't see where. There is a method call to `Route<T>` but nowhere `PostData<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeserializeObject()` can handle plain strings as long as they are quoted:

```cs
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"test\"");
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/35qWGB

In case you cannot change the endpoint you can simply create a second overload of `PostData()` that doesn't do any deserialization:

```cs
public string PostData(string url, object content) 
{
  // other lines of code setting up client in between .. ignoring them  for readability

  return client.UploadString(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), contentString);
}
```

You could also do something weird like:

```cs
public T PostData<T>(string url, object content) 
{
  // other lines of code setting up client in between .. ignoring them  for readability

  var response = client.UploadString(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), contentString);
  return typeof(T) == typeof(string)
    ? (T)(object)response
    : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response, settings);
}
```